# Just another suggested edit-suggestion suggestion

Tags: feature-request, review, suggested-edits, wording

Instead of seeing:

> (username) has approved 297 **edit suggestions** and rejected 121 **edit suggestions** and improved 21 **edit suggestions**

Can that be rephrased to this?

> (username) has approved 297, rejected 121, and improved 21 **edit suggestions**

Or perhaps something better? The duplicated *edit suggestions* seems wordy and superfluous and redundant. [Standard conjunction reduction in English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordination_(linguistics)#Non-constituent_conjuncts) would naturally remove the common bits between elements joined by the coördinating conjunction, so the current wording sounds somewhat un-Englishy.

What are your thoughts? Or is this a pointless suggestion?

Comment: Thanks to @tchrist for improving my question and migrating it here. :)

Comment: @Sha it's not a dupe. The proposed wording is different.

Comment: @DEAD Yeah, but I've posted an [answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/283953/309993) under the dupe question, and it is "accepted" now. So there's that. :)

Answer (score 10):

IMO, yes, it's a bit of a pointless suggestion. The current version sacrifices brevity for clarity, which on the whole is probably a good thing since clarity is, at the end of the day, more important.

Comment: And the current wording is certainly technically easier to implement than deciding where *and* should only appear once.