# Too many "and's" in Reviewer Stats

Tags: bug, review, suggested-edits, grammar

In the Suggested Edits Reviewer Stats, I saw that the Reviewer has no commas and lots of "and"s:

[image]

Whereas the Editor Stats do have commas and don't run on.  Small bug, but can we give the stats some commas so it's less of a mouthful?

Comment: Well... it's [grammatically valid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polysyndeton), but I have no idea why they would choose to write it that way.

Comment: I love the table in [this answer on the dupe](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/277474/152859), will be better than just adding commas.